# Paste as HTML content in Sublime 2

Tags: html, copy, sublimetext2, paste

I would like to copy text from a web page and paste it into sublime as html code. So, copy something like this:

## Heading

Foo. **Bar**.

and paste into sublime like this:

`<h1>Heading</h1>
<p>Foo. <strong>Bar</strong>.</p>`

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Quite a bit of web research to see if someone else has found a solution to this. I've seen it implemented in other programs (like Notepad++ and any wysiwyg editor), and because Sublime is so extensible, I thought it was possible that there was some way I wasn't seeing.

Comment: there's an outstanding request in userecho as well.. https://sublimetext.userecho.com/topics/4771-paste-html-formatted-content-from-clipboard/

Answer (score -1):

Turn on the Developer mode on your browser, say Chrome.

On the respective element, in this case `Heading` , right click and select Inspect Element. This would open a small developer's window at the bottom of your browser, with the html element being selected in the source of the html.

Right click and Copy Node. Paste it in any text editor.

Hope this would work.

Comment: That would work, for sure, but it's several steps. I have to do this all day long. Notepad ++ can do this (under Paste Special), but I prefer sublime.

Comment: Ohhh. Look for any plugin over sublime. I guess there may be some.